# Is it possible to deploy "next/react + node/express" web application into one server account, like heroku?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, deployment, next.js

I'm a building a web application with Next.js/React.js + Node.js.

I would like to deploy my application not separately but into one server(e.g. Heroku).

How could I do this and make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Using package npm i -D concurrently you can run your both projects on same server.
Use this link fo reference 
https://dev.to/numtostr/running-react-and-node-js-in-one-shot-with-concurrently-2oac

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer. I'll try concurrently.

Answer (score 1):

Never used next, but I had a similar problem last night and tried like 5 different things to no avail.

Found this today and walked thru his demo and got a better understanding of what's going on and was able to restructure my project to get it to work.  This post walks thru how to have Express serve your React project using heroku-postbuild.

Other things that tripped me up: I needed two package.json files (one for Express and one for React) and I didn't have my express app directory set to find index.html

https://daveceddia.com/deploy-react-express-app-heroku/